# On X-s-permutable subgroups of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, abstract-algebra

I want to prove Lemma 2.1(1) in the paper On X-s-Permutable Subgroups of a Finite Group by Min Bang SU, Yang Ming LI. It is on the web.
This is my proof.
. 
Since $H$ is $X−s−$permutable in $G$, then for $P$ Sylow of $G$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $P^{x}H=HP^{x}$. The Sylow of $N$ are of the form $P∩N$. Thus,$(P∩N)^{x}H=H(P∩N)^{x}$. 
Hence, $H$ is $X−s−$permutable in $N$.

The problem is, according to the definition in the second page, that $X \subseteq G$ but in my proof $X$ may not be a subset of $N$.

Comment: It would be better if you gave a reference for the paper.

Comment: I believe it is "On X-s-permutable subgroups of a finite group", by Min Ban Su and Yang Ming Li. But the question is still inappropriate. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, if I have done something wrong.

Comment: The question falls under the rubric of "too localized" -- proving lemmas in papers is not of general interest...

Comment: I think the post falls into the category of "not a well posed question".  If it could be made clear and specific as to what is desired, as well as what has been tried, such a revised question might be suitable for MathOverflow.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.04.23